# Basic mathematical operation

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig

How to do a basic mathematical operation with Pig Latin?
I entered the Grunt shell and tried for example `dump 1+2;`, but got

> 2014-11-28 23:23:48,011 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt
>   - ERROR 2997: Encountered IOException. No previously defined alias found. Please define an alias and use 'dump' operator.

**Update**

Doing `A = 1 + 2 DUMP A` I get:

```
grunt> A = 1 + 2 DUMP A
>> [ENTER]
>> [ENTER]
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use pig grunt shell as something like python shell. Pig is data flow language and it takes relation as input and produces another relation as output. 
Pig stmts are generally organized in this form

```
1.LOAD stmt to load data from local file system or HDFS file system
2.A series of stmts to process the data using pig built-in function or Custom UDF
3.DUMP stmt to display the data in console, it will take only relation as input(No constant values as you mentioned)
4.STORE stmt to store the output into local file system or HDFS file system
```

**Example:**
**input.txt**

```
1,5,10.0
2,6,20.0
3,7,30.0
```

**Load the file from local filesystem using delimiter as ','**

```
A = LOAD 'input.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (f1:int,f2:int,f3:float);
```

**Process the data, Add,diff and div**

```
B = FOREACH A GENERATE f1+10 AS sum, f2-2 AS diff, f3/10 AS div;
```

**Display the result in console**

```
DUMP B;
```

You can execute the series of pig stmts either from grunt shell or thru pig script

**Grunt shell:**

```
grunt> A = LOAD 'input.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (f1:int,f2:int,f3:float);
grunt> B = FOREACH A GENERATE f1+10 AS sum, f2-2 AS diff, f3/10 AS div;
grunt> DUMP B;
(11,2,1.0)
(12,3,2.0)
(13,4,3.0)
```

**Pig script:**

```
1.Add the above three lines of pig stmt into a file Ex: test.pig
2.Run from terminal
```

> pig -x local test.pig (local mode)
>
> pig test.pig   (or)  pig -x mapreduce test.pig  (mapreduce mode)

Please refer the basic pig documentation, it will help you lot more
https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.13.0/basic.html#artichmetic-ops

Answer (score 0):

https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#Arithmetic+Operators

this gives example of arithmetic operators with PIG.

DUMP is to display an array of result data.